# How to find the week day of (any) given date?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions, calendar-computations

How to find the week day of any given date?

Say we need to know in which week-day was June $25,2019$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846897/how-to-find-the-day-of-the-week-for-a-given-date, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16945/calculate-which-day-of-the-week-a-date-falls-in-using-modular-arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the week-day of a given date, we need to:

- find out whether the given year is "common" or "leap".
- know $\mod(a,b)$.
- know $\left \lfloor a \right \rfloor$.

---

To find out whether the given year is "common" or "leap", we can use the following chart:

### [image]

$\mod(a,b)$ means the remainder when dividing $a$ by $b$. For example, when we divide $17$ by $3$, we get $5$ and the remainder is $2$. Therefore, $\mod(17,3)=2$.

For convince, $\mod(a,100)=$ the number formed by the last two digits of $a$. For example, $\mod(13527,100)=27$.

---

$\left \lfloor a \right \rfloor$ means the nearst integer less than or equal to $a$. For examples,

$\left \lfloor 6.97 \right \rfloor=6$,$\left \lfloor -2.8 \right \rfloor=-3,\left \lfloor \frac{20}{4} \right \rfloor=5$.

---

> Suppose that the given date is of the form: MONTH $d, y$

We have to calculate the following:

- $A=\mod(y,100)$
- $B=\left \lfloor \frac{A}{4} \right \rfloor$
- $C=\frac{y-A}{100}$
- $D = d$ which is the given date.
- $E =\left \lfloor \frac{C}{4} \right \rfloor$
- $F=0,3,2,5,0,3,5,1,4,6,2,$ or $4$ depending on the given month (Jan, Feb, March, ..., or Dec) respectively.
- $G=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  0 & \text{if the month is not Jan nor Feb}\\
  1 & \text{for Jan or Feb in a common year}\\ 
  2 & \text{for Jan or Feb in a leap year}
  \end{matrix}\right.$
- $H=\mod(A+B-2C+D+E+F-G,7)$
- The week-day depends on the $H$ value,
  $0$ for Sunday, $1$ for Monday, $2$ for Tuesday, $3$ for Wednesday, $4$ for Thursday, $5$ for Friday, and $6$ for Saturday.

---

> Consider the example, June $25,2019$

Since $2019$ is not divisible by $4$, then $2019$ is a common year.

$A=\mod(2019,100)=19$

$B= \left \lfloor \frac{19}{4} \right \rfloor=4$

$C=\frac{2019-19}{100}=20$

$D= 25$ as given.

$E= \left \lfloor \frac{20}{4} \right \rfloor=5$

$F=3$ for June.

$G=0$ since the given month is neither Jan nor Feb.

$H=\mod(19+4-2\times20+25+5+3-0,7)=\mod(16,7)=2=$ Tuesday.

---

I noticed that many people ask about this. I posted this way because I think it is the simplest way for any given date , whatever the given century.

There are some simpler ways but for years between 2000 and 2099 only.

So it is a general way.

If you know any simpler way than this, please leave a comment or just post it as an answer, THANKS!.

This may be a useful page for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: I believe your algorithm for determining if a year is leap is wrong, given that a year divisible by 4 and not by 100 should be a leap year

Comment: @karmalu I did not get your point dear. May you clarify that, please?

Comment: If i understand correctly the chart you posted it seems that a year that is divisible by 4 and not by 100 like 2020 should be common while, in fact, it will be a leap year.

Comment: @karmalu You are right! I will correct the chart and will edit it. Thanks.

Comment: @karmalu Can you please check my edit to the chart?